# Select top using NHibernate custom dialect to OpenEdge database does not work

Tags: nhibernate, openedge, dialect

I have made a custom dialect to be able to use NHibernate with a Progress/OpenEdge database over ODBC. In most cases the dialect works fine, but I have a problem with SELECT TOP statements. The problem is that the statements are generated as the following with the amount of columns to return as a parameter:

```
SELECT TOP ? SomeColumn
FROM SomeTable
where SomeColumn = ?; p0 = 100, p1 = 'test'
```

The Progress/Openedge database does not support this, so I would like to make some changes to the dialect, forcing the statement to not use parameters for the amount of columns in SELECT TOP - like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 SomeColumn
FROM SomeTable
where SomeColumn = ?; p0 = 'test'
```

Is this possible?

By the way, im using NHibernate v. 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [NHibernate's source code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Dialect.cs), I would say that you need to override `SupportsVariableLimit` property to return `false`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Can parameters be used for a statement containing a LIMIT?
/// </summary>
public override bool SupportsVariableLimit
{
    get { return false; }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Unfortunately, [it seems](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/ResultOperatorProcessors/ProcessTake.cs) that NHibernate Linq doesn't use `SupportsVariableLimit` property. It always tries to use parameters.

Here's [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nhibernate-development/TZVi8ce_Vfo) on that, with a source code fix.

Comment: I have tried that, but I will then get an exception from the Dialect.GetLimitString method saying "Dialect does not support variable limits." - this happens because the limitparameter parameter is not null, while the limit parameter IS null...